# Old Enum Behaviour is used, please upgrade to the new one

Tags: node.js, typescript, macos-catalina

I'm encountering this weird message out of blue on my Node server (Express + GraphQL) in the terminal window. Message doesn't say where it comes from.

Anyone experiencing this problem or any idea why it's happening?

[Github Issue in Typegoose Repository](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/124)

Comment: I started getting this error after upgrading the Typegoose, Mongoose and MongoDB NPM packages in my project. Did you recently upgrade one of these in yours?

Comment: I upgraded all my packages in monorepo project via VS's [NPM dependency](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=howardzuo.vscode-npm-dependency) extension. After getting this error, I also thought that it might be related to these packages (I also use TypeGraphQL). I rolled back changes, reset modules but the error still appears. Have you got rid of it already?

Comment: Same problem here, I started getting this error after upgrading Mongoose and Typegoose to the new repository (it got moved).

Comment: Taking a look through the `node_modules` folder, I can see the warning being logged by Typegoose. See `prop.js`. Still need to figure out why though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typegoose is changing how it handles `enum` properties, and the old behaviour is deprecated.

#### Check for breaking changes

If you are working on an existing project, then review the documentation to ensure your app and DB will be compatible with the new behaviour:

- [Enum properties](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/decorators/prop/#enum)
- [`useNewEnum` flag](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/functions/setGlobalOptions/)

#### Opt-in to the new enum behaviour

Run the following as early as possible in your start-up code:

```
import { setGlobalOptions } from "@typegoose/typegoose";

setGlobalOptions({
  globalOptions: {
    useNewEnum: true,
  },
});
```

If you still get the warnings, then try the following:

- Ensure the code is running before any other app start-up logic
- Run the code before any other `import`s

Comment: Thanks @Sam, this was enlightening. I imported `setGlobalOptions` and called it immediately in the entry file, but the messages still appear. Is it because the warnings are being logged? I opened an issue in the [GitHub](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/124).

Comment: @MehmetN.Yarar, I had the same problem but fixed it by moving the code to the earliest possible point in my code. Maybe there are other conditions that trigger the warnings. Thanks for raising the GitHub issue. Looking forward to getting a definitive answer from the developer! :)

Comment: In my case, it was an [import order issue](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/124#issuecomment-554420725) because I had to import model classes in order to use in a middleware :)